# Modify the python script that inserts data from a text file into an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, anytree

I need a python script that reads some trees from a text file and puts them in an excel file. Go through each tree from the last node to the root and enter the data in a specified excel. The text file contains trees with nodes that contain information separated by semicolon.Each tree is separated by double space in the file. Start with the last node in the tree and enter the data up to the root node in Excel.

The script writes for each subnode in the Routing column, the part code of the parent, with the exception of the root node, which has an empty Routing.

The text file contains:

```
100201F, Part name, Part description, 1, False
├── C002L0, Part name, Part description, 1, False
    ├── V3fd1, Part name, Part description ,  1, True
    |-─ 1002011, Part name, Part description:, 1,  True
    ├── TT001HU, Part name, Part description, 1, True


134545F,Part name, Part description, 1, False
├── ...
...
```

Here's the script I've managed to do so far, but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


# define the column names for the excel file
column_names = ["Routing", "Part code", "Part name", "Part description", "Batch size","Is material"]

# read the trees from the text file
with open("trees.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    trees = file.read().strip().split("\n\n")

# create an empty dataframe to store the results
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

# loop through each tree
for tree in trees:
    # split the tree into nodes and reverse the order
    nodes = tree.strip().split("\n")[::-1]

    # loop through each node
    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        # split the node into its data
        data = node.strip().split(";")

        # add the data to a dictionary
        row_data = {
            "Routing": re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', data[0]) if i != len(nodes)-1 else "",
            "Part code": re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', data[0]),
            "Part name": data[1],
            "Part description": data[2],
            "Batch size": data[3],
            "Is material": data[4]
        }

        # add the child node to the "Routing" column if the current node is not the root
        if i < len(nodes)-1:
            child_data = nodes[i+1].strip().split(";")
            row_data["Routing"] = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', child_data[0])

        # add the row to the dataframe
        df = df.append(row_data, ignore_index=True)

# write the dataframe to an Excel file
df.to_excel("trees.xlsx", index=False)
```

The script does not traverse the tree correctly. For example, for the code TT001HU, put the routing code 1002011 instead of C002L0.

I would like the excel to look like this:

```
Parent code    Part name    Part description    Batch size    Routing    Is material
TT001HU        Part name    Part description    1             C002L0     True
1002011        Part name    Part description    1             C002L0     True
V3fd1          Part name    Part description    1             C002L0     True
C002L0         Part name    Part description    1             100201F    False
100201F        Part name    Part description    1                        False
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your tree file looks this way:

```
100201F;Part name;Part description;1;False
├── C002L0;Part name;Part description;1;False
    ├── V3fd1;Part name;Part description;1;True
    |-─ 1002011;Part name;Part description;1;True
    ├── TT001HU;Part name;Part description;1;True

134545F;Part name;Part description;1;False
├── C002L1;Part name;Part description;1;False
    ├── V3fd2;Part name;Part description;1;True
    ├── 1002012;Part name;Part description;1;True
    ├── TT001HV;Part name;Part description;1;True
```

then the correct code to do this is

```
import pandas as pd
import re
column_names = ["Parent code", "Part name", "Part description", "Batch size", "Routing", "Is material"]

with open("tree.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    trees = file.read().strip().split("\n\n")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

for tree in trees:
    nodes = tree.strip().split("\n")[::-1]

    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        data = node.strip().split(";")

        row_data = {
            "Parent code": "" if i == 0 else re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', nodes[i-1].strip().split(";")[0]),
            "Part name": data[1],
            "Part description": data[2],
            "Batch size": data[3],
            "Routing": "" if i == len(nodes)-1 else re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', nodes[i+1].strip().split(";")[0]),
            "Is material": data[4]
        }

        df = df.append(row_data, ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel("trees.xlsx", index=False)
```

which will give you

[image]

**EDIT: Your particular case**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

column_names = ["Parent code", "Part name", "Part description", "Batch size", "Routing", "Is material"]

with open("trees.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    trees = file.read().strip().split("\n\n")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

for tree in trees:
    # split the tree into nodes and reverse the order
    nodes = tree.strip().split("\n")[::-1]
    parent = ""

    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        # split the node into its data
        data = node.strip().split(", ")
        
        row_data = {
            "Parent code": parent,
            "Part name": data[1],
            "Part description": data[2],
            "Batch size": data[3],
            "Routing": re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', data[0]),
            "Is material": data[4]
        }

        parent = row_data["Routing"]
        
        df = df.append(row_data, ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel("output2.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: You can adapt it to your needs, no?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but according to your example file, I would need the excel to look like this:
~
Part code   Part name   Part description   Batch size  Routong   Is material 

100201F     Part name   Part description  1                                  FALSE 
C002L0       Part name   Part description  1                100201F    FALSE 
V3fd1         Part name   Part description  1                 C002L0     TRUE 
1002011     Part name   Part description  1                 C002L1     TRUE 
TT001HU    Part name   Part description  1                 C002L2     TRUE 
~
Thank you!

Comment: If you can help me, it would be great

Comment: I made an edit to my answer

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if it was what you wanted